# Trace route implementation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking

I have been trying to write a simple trace route implementation for python; please find the code below.

```
import socket

def main (HostName):
    dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(HostName)
    TTL = 1    #Define the time to live as 1. Will be incremented by one after each UDP message has been sent
    Max = 30



while True:
    ICMP_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) #Create socket that can receive ICMP 
    UDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP) #Create socket that will send UDP messages 
    UDP.setsockopt(0,4,TTL)
    
    
    
    ICMP_socket.bind(("",33434)) #33434 is the default port used for traceroute 
    message = "Hi" #The message we send is an empty string 
    UDP.sendto(message.encode(),(dest_addr, 33434))
    
   
    
    Receiver = (0,"")
    Router_addr = None
    
    
    try:
        Receiver = ICMP_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        Router_addr = Receiver[1]
        if Router_addr == None:
            print("*")
        else:
            print(Router_addr)
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        ICMP_socket.close()
        UDP.close()
    
    TTL = TTL + 1
    
    if Router_addr == dest_addr or TTL == Max:
        break
    
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    main('google.com')
```

I am running it on my macOS terminal with sudo because it needs root privileges. However, the output I am getting seems to be wrong. The first IP is my local IP, the second one is an IP I do not know, and the rest are all google's ip. It is not outputting the intermediate IPs and it is only breaking when reaching the TTL limit of 30.

This is the output (I removed the first Ip which is local IP address):

```
('172.30.224.110', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
('172.217.19.46', 0)
```

Can anyone help? I do not seem to be able to find the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why the program does not stop**

The program does not stop when it "reaches" the destination because you have overlooked that `address`, you call it `Router_addr`, for `AF_INET` is a `tuple` (see "Socket families" in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)). This can be seen also by the output you included in your question (which is the result of `print(Router_addr)`).

If you update `if Router_addr == dest_addr or TTL == Max:` to be as shown below, your program will stop.

```py
if Router_addr[0] == dest_addr or TTL == Max:
```

**What does the output show**

I cannot know your network topology and how you reach the Internet in general, and google specifically. From what you describe and see in your output.

- `172.30.224.110` is a private IP address of (very likely) an internal-facing interface of a router of your provider; recall that the response is sent to your machine from the interface that is "closer" to you, not the one that is "closer" to the Internet (I assume that as you mention, you do not recognize this IP address as belonging to your [say, home, university] router/network)
- there may not be multiple hops between the google IP address (172.217.19.46) and the router above; this can be, for instance the case, if google's servers are located on your provider's network (a very common practice for big content providers and CDN's to achieve high performance to end users of large eyeball providers); from my machine, I see multiple hops to google running your program (perhaps you want to check another destination)
- the most unclear piece is why you see an IP address of your machine in the first row; this may be because you are using you Mac as a router (perhaps for Internet sharing) or in a "strange" configuration that involves forwarding (and therefore the first router is your machine); I assume here that when you are talking about your **local IP address** you do not mean the **loopback IP address** (otherwise please read below)

**Why is the loopback address in the output**

If what you see for some network hosts (perhaps including your first hop) in the path is the **loopback IP address** instead of the address you sent the packet to, the reason is the snippet below (and what happens in the background):

```py
if Router_addr == None:
    print("*")
```

When a network node is not responsive `socket.recvfrom()` returns `('127.0.0.1', 0)`, which is not `None`. This is because for `UDP` an `ICMP Destination Unreachable` (Type 3) `Port Unreachable` (Code 3) is generated by the `localhost` when nothing is listening at the target port. This is by the way the reason why `ICMP_socket.recvfrom(1024)` does not stay blocked.

Your corrected program, modified slightly to print `TTL`s and `ICMP` types and codes, gives (**see, `TTL: [6]`**):

```py
$ sudo python3 trorig.py
('192.168.178.1', 0) TTL: [1] type: [11] code: [0]
('62.245.142.131', 0) TTL: [2] type: [11] code: [0]
('62.245.142.130', 0) TTL: [3] type: [11] code: [0]
('82.135.16.226', 0) TTL: [4] type: [11] code: [0]
('142.250.161.214', 0) TTL: [5] type: [11] code: [0]
('127.0.0.1', 0) TTL: [6] type: [3] code: [3]       
('172.253.75.128', 0) TTL: [7] type: [11] code: [0]
('172.253.75.143', 0) TTL: [8] type: [11] code: [0]
('74.125.244.81', 0) TTL: [9] type: [11] code: [0]
('172.253.75.141', 0) TTL: [10] type: [11] code: [0]
('172.217.23.78', 0) TTL: [11] type: [3] code: [3]
```

The respective tcpdump output is (**note that there is no row for the unresponsive network host, 142.250.161.214 is followed by 172.253.75.128,**):

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i en0 -nnn icmp      
Password:
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
14:30:45.720700 IP 192.168.178.1 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:45.740808 IP 62.245.142.131 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:45.761857 IP 62.245.142.130 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
14:30:45.782603 IP 82.135.16.226 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 36
14:30:45.803874 IP 142.250.161.214 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:53.454002 IP 172.253.75.128 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 76
14:30:53.476512 IP 172.253.75.143 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:53.496455 IP 74.125.244.81 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:53.519329 IP 172.253.75.141 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 38
14:30:53.541726 IP 172.217.23.78 > 192.168.178.20: ICMP 172.217.23.78 udp port 33434 unreachable, length 36
```

A corresponding traceroute output is (there are some differences in the path compared to the above, as did not run it at the same time, but the point remains that **the network host at TTL: [6] is unresponsive**):

```
$ traceroute -n google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.23.78), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.178.1  8.694 ms  2.893 ms  3.095 ms
 2  62.245.142.131  17.545 ms  17.361 ms  19.010 ms
 3  62.245.142.130  25.948 ms  20.302 ms  26.077 ms
 4  82.135.16.226  20.418 ms  19.967 ms  21.411 ms
 5  142.250.161.214  29.145 ms  25.573 ms  19.979 ms
 6  * * *
 7  108.170.247.113  26.875 ms
    172.253.75.146  21.736 ms
    108.170.247.113  21.987 ms
 8  172.253.75.143  22.435 ms
    172.253.75.141  20.617 ms
    108.170.247.120  21.670 ms
 9  172.217.23.78  19.538 ms
    74.125.244.97  18.503 ms
    74.125.244.81  18.907 ms
```

So, the way you are checking for unresponsive network hosts in not correct. You may want to update it to something like:

```
if Router_addr == ('127.0.0.1', 0) :
    print("*")
```

Two last points you may want to consider:

- As seen above, not every host (or network) will send you back a response and responses may get lost or dropped. You may want to include a timeout for how long you are willing to wait in your `ICMP_socket.recvfrom(1024)` before giving up and declaring that a network host is not responsive. You can look at `socket.SO_RCVTIMEO`.
- As also seen above, there may be multiple network hosts at a given `TTL` away from your machine towards the destination. You may want to consider sending multiple packets to discover them (if they are discoverable).

**Edit (answering to a comment below):** the original code needed some small modifications to run without issues; below is the updated and enhanced code

```py
import socket
import struct

def main (HostName):
    dest_addr = socket.gethostbyname(HostName)
    TTL = 1    
    Max = 30

    while True:
        ICMP_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_ICMP) 
        ICMP_socket.bind(("",33434))

        UDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)    
        UDP.setsockopt(0,4,TTL)
        message = "Hi" 
        UDP.sendto(message.encode(),(dest_addr, 33434))

        Router_addr = None
        try:
            Data, Router_addr = ICMP_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            ICMP_header = Data[20:28] 
            type_, code, *_ = struct.unpack('bbHHh', ICMP_header)                      

            if Router_addr == ('127.0.0.1', 0) :
                print(f"* TTL: [{TTL}] type: [{type_}] code: [{code}]")
            else:
                print(f"{Router_addr} TTL: [{TTL}] type: [{type_}] code: [{code}]")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            ICMP_socket.close()
            UDP.close()
        
        TTL = TTL + 1
        
        if Router_addr[0] == dest_addr or TTL == Max:
            break
    
if __name__ =="__main__":
    main('google.com')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I was able to fix the first issue, but I am afraid I am still not seeing the " * " when I do not get a response. Do you think it might be because of the exception? I replaced my if statement with the one you recommended but it is not working. How were you able to do it on row six? Every time I don't have a response the program just runs infinitely. I am also looking at socket.SO_RCVTIMEO to implement it.

Comment: @Proto: I added the code at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Are you running it on windows? Because for some reason on my Mac its also not showing when there is a type 3 code 3

Comment: Nope, I'm on Mac. Try printing out `Router_addr` and see what it is (from which IP address, you get the `Port unreachable` message). Then, you will be able to update the `if` condition accordingly.

Comment: And, yep, my first point in my "Two last points" was exactly for avoiding such situations. If you do not get a response in a reasonable time then you infer that there is "something" wrong. That "something" may be on the host or on the network (e.g., some middlebox, a router that drops, delays ICMP). traceroute uses IIRC a timeout of 5s to "catch all" those conditions,. You can "implement" this with something like `timeout = struct.pack("ll", 5, 0)` and `ICMP_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, timeout)` [untested, you may need to adapt it for Mac a bit].

Comment: Thank you! I just added the timeout; I am getting this error now: if Router_addr[0] == dest_addr or TTL == Max:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable                                                                           I'll work on it some more and see if I can fix it; but really I am very grateful for all your input and support! Thank you!!!! Have a nice day